# Difference between "without using extra memory" and "use constant memory"

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

When I was practicing algorithms with OJ, I saw these two requirements a lot. Does this two requirements mean the same thing?

For example:

137. Single Number II: Could you implement it without using extra memory?
138. Single Number III: Could you implement it using only constant space complexity?

Comment: Probably not the same. "no extra space" is certainly not the same as "only a fixed amount of extra space" (of course, the author might intend to mean the same, though)

Answer (score 2):

No.

Without using extra memory usually implies that you can overwrite the input; so it uses more memory for larger inputs (but just that memory - nothing more). (A small constant space is usually allowed as well, e.g. for the stack of the function.)

Constant space complexity usually implies that you are not allowed to overwrite the input and you can only use a small constant space.

Answer (score 0):

They do not mean the same.

> Could you implement it without using extra memory?

This means that you cannot use any additional space apart from the given input.

> Could you implement it using only constant space complexity?

Whereas this means the additional space you use to solve the problem should be a constant irrespective of the input size.